# Use printer as wireless access point

Tags: printer, wireless-access-point

I own a HP Officejet 6700 printer. It has both LAN/Wireless and USB connectivity. Since it is placed in a location where the Wi-Fi signal is weak, I use the wired Ethernet cable to connect it to a switch. It works fine.

Now, I'm wondering: could I use it as a Wireless Access point to strengthen the Wi-Fi signal in that remote place?

I've tried meddling with the settings but it seems to allow either wifi or Ethernet, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, as HP Officejet 6700 Printers can only be clients to wireless networks. If you wish to extend the range of your WiFi network, you should get a wireless repeater, or a bridged WiFi router.

Answer (score 3):

For any device to work as a Wireless Access Point, certain drivers (or packages) are required which can make that device as a WAP.

Printers use to have firmware which have limited functionalities and it also doesn't supports installing of packages (or drivers) manually. So, Answer is NO. Your printer cannot act as wireless access point.

Why not your install Raspberry Pi which can work as WAP and it will be a cheap solution also.

Comment: Please don't use quotes or `code` for formatting. Thanks.